# Notation for points in 2d or 3d coordinate systems P(a|b|c)? Origin and reasons?

Tags: notation, vectors, education

In every german high school book about vector geometry, points in 2d or 3d cartesian coordinate systems are denoted like $P(2|-1|5)$. Very rarely one also reads something like $P = P(2|-1|5)$. But I have never seen $P = (2|-1|5)$ (or $|$ replaced by $,$ or $;$).

What is the origin of this notation and what is the reason for using it?

And the other way around: The notation above seems to be so "hard coded" into the german abitur problems that letting students write $P = (2|-1|5)$ feels to be wrong in some way though I don't see any reason for it. Are there any pretty-minded reasons why this notation should not be used?

However the first notation seems to be ugly because if you write something like:

$$
A(1|2|3), B(4|5|6) \implies \vec{AB} = \begin{pmatrix}3\\3 \\3 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Doesn't seem to make sense because $A(1|2|3), B(4|5|6)$ doesn't read like a statement.

However

$$
A = (1|2|3), B = (4|5|6) \implies \vec{AB} = \begin{pmatrix}3\\3 \\3 \end{pmatrix}
$$

seems to be much more like math notation is used in allmost all other areas.

Similar problem with something like:

$$
B(4|5|6) \text{ and } \vec{AB} = \begin{pmatrix}3\\3 \\3 \end{pmatrix}\implies A(1|2|3)
$$

Would be great if someone could clarify the points above.

Comment: Interesting. I've never seen this notation, only $P = (a,b,c)$ -- or $P = (a:b:c)$ for points in the projective plane. On the other hand, I never studied in Germany (although I studied in the Netherlands for a while)...